# why select for update works properly only with versioned entity?

Tags: sql, database, spring, transactions, hsqldb

I use HSQLDB 2.4.1 with Spring data-jpa.
I see that another thread is able to update the same row if field '@Version' is absent.
2 threads running by Spring '@Scheduled' updating records with special status meaning it hasn't been processed yet.

Reading method in Repository:

```
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_READ)
@Query("select t from Task t where t.state = 0")
Page<Task> findUnprocessed(Pageable p);
```

'process1' and 'process2' do almost the same simple update but 'process1' has longer pause before saving.

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10)
@Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRED)
public void process1() throws Exception {
    try {
        Task task = getTasks();
        System.out.println("process1: " + task + " by " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        task.data= task.data + " by 1";
        task.state = 1;
        Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(4_000));
        repo.save(task);
        System.out.println("process1 updated: " + task.id);
        System.out.println("process1 read same = " + repo.findById(task.id));
    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

Log of processing:

```
process1: Task(id=1) by thr-1
process2: Task(id=1) by thr-2
process2 updated: 1
process2 read same = Task(id=1, data= by 2) <<!!!
process2: Task(id=2, data=) by thr-2
process2 updated: 2
process2 read same = Task(id=2, data= by 2)
process1 updated: 1
process1 read same = Task(id=1, data= by 1) <<!!!
```

As a result Task#1 is updated by 'process1' after it has been already updated by process2. Why if 'lock for update' has been used?
Everything works ok with '@Version' field (process2 got exception then).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the concurrency control model of the HSQLDB database. If you want pessimistic locking, use `SET DATABASE TRANSACTION CONTROL LOCKS`. This enables both read locks and write locks.

See the Guide for details http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sessions-chapt.html#snc_tx_tx_cc